# ODS functionality in R

Tags: r

Is there any functionality in R which is just like that of ODS functionality in SAS?

Comment: what does ods functionality in SAS do for those who don't use SAS

Comment: [This ODS](http://support.sas.com/rnd/base/ods/index.html)?

Comment: A quick perusal of that link makes me think there isn't going to be one specific R function that duplicates ALL of ODS. What format are you trying to output results into? Flat files? Look at `write.table()`. JPEGs or other images? Look at `jpeg()`, `bmp()` et al. HTML? Look at `R2HTML` package or perhaps `xtable()`. PDFs? Look at `pdf()`? PDFs via LaTeX? Look at `sweave()`, `xtable()`, and others. Word or Word like programs? Look at `odfweave()`. This is by no means an exhaustive list...

Comment: as @Chase said. R also doesn't have a data step and a proc step, but you have a whole set of functions for data manipulation and analysis. If you have a specific problem, be welcome to ask here, but as your question stands now, it's too vague and overly broad.

Comment: @Joris:When I'm working in R, the output comes within the console. I want to see the outputs in more presentable format, as given in case of ods functionality in sas. Since I didn't know whether such functionality are available in R or now, I posted this question. I guess it's very relevant in terms of R question. Maybe I should have elaborate my question a bit more.

Comment: @user697363 : nothing personal, it's the site's policy. See also the FAQ : http://stackoverflow.com/faq . I do agree this is an interesting question, but one can (and did) write a book about it. That's why - for this site - the question is too broad.  Everything you can do with ODS, you can do with R as well. How, that's going to be quite some chapters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Joris mentioned, some more details on your end will help us help you. In the mean time, here are some links to the functions / resources listed above to get you started:

- *Flat files* - look at `?write.table`. You can easily write out comma, tab, or other arbitrary delimited files
- *Images* - look at `?jpeg`. There are equivalent functions for bmp, png, and tiff
- *HTML output* - CRAN package [R2HTML](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R2HTML/index.html) and [xtable](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xtable/index.html)
- *PDFs* - single or multipage PDFs can be generated with `?pdf`
- *PDF via LaTeX* - look at `?Sweave`. This is not for the faint of heart if you don't understand LaTex. Also look at [lyx](http://www.lyx.org/) for an alternative though I have no experience there. [brew](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/brew/index.html) is another templating approach that looks promising as well.
- *Word or word like documents* - look at package [odfWeave](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/odfWeave/index.html) or [r2wd](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R2wd/index.html) or [R2PPT](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R2PPT/index.html)

In general, take a look at the [ReproducibleResearch](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/ReproducibleResearch.html) task view on CRAN for other alternatives and more details about the above.

Comment: For HTML there's also [hwriter package](http://cran.r-project.org/package=hwriter).

Comment: Thanks a lot Chase! The answer is really helpful.